# JSON parsing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Im trying to get the value for "query"

```
[
    {
        "query"=> "cat",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "dream catcher",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat ears",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat collar",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat costume",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat shirt",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat ring",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat toys",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat bed",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cheshire cat",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "query"=> "cat tree",
        "search_type_names"=> [
            "in Handmade"
        ],
        "search_types"=> [
            "handmade"
        ]
    },
    {
        "link"=> "/search/shops?search_query=cat",
        "query"=> "find shop names containing cat",
        "search_type_names"=> [],
        "search_types"=> []
    }
]
```

Comment: Ive tried json["query"] and it returns a conversion error from integer to string....

Comment: Your input is an array. If you wanted it to be a string, you need quotes. It's helpful to assign all inputs to a variable (e.g., `arr = [...]` or `str = "..."`). That allows those offering answers or posting comments to refer to the variable without having to define it. Also, when you report an exception, be specific about the exception message and the line where it was raised.

Comment: Reduce your input data to the bare minimum useful to demonstrate the problem you are seeing. Anything beyond that only wastes our time helping you. Also, as is, it looks like you want us to write the code for you. What did you write?

Comment: This is the minimum useful information to get the answer I need. So if I add all the code before this problem it would waste your time. And writing this wasn't a waste of your time?...

Answer (score 2):

It appears you've already converted the JSON string to an array, which I call `arr`, in which case:

```
arr.map { |h| h["query"] }
  #=> ["cat", "dream catcher", "cat ears", "cat collar", "cat costume",
  #    "cat shirt", "cat ring", "cat toys", "cat bed", "cheshire cat",
  #    "cat tree", "find shop names containing cat"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since that JSON is an array, you'll have to first choose one of the elements from the array, and then use the key for the hash to extract 'query'

```
json.first['query']
json[5]['query']
```

Answer (score 0):

Letting `json_array` is the array of JSON that you have, you can get the `query`s this way too:

```
json_array.each { |a| puts a['query'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Lets you have `a` a that the array of JSON

```
irb(main):151:0> a.collect{|h| h["query"]}
=> ["cat", "dream catcher", "cat ears", "cat collar", "cat costume", "cat shirt", "cat ring", "cat toys", "cat bed", "cheshire cat", "cat tree", "find shop names containing cat"]
```